# camera not targeting deathCameraTarget on player death

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-development

It has been quite a while since I last spent time coding and I am rather inexperienced. This code is designed to look at the player when the player is alive but switch to looking at the object deathCameraTarget when the player dies. for some reason the camera doesn't switch to targeting the deathCameraTarget.

this is my camera motor script (controlling what the camera looks like:
using UnityEngine;

```
public class CameraMotor : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float boundX = 0.001f;
    public float boundY = 0.001f;

    [SerializeField]
    private Transform lookAt;
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform originalLookAt;

    private Fighter player;  // Assuming fighter is the class that contains IsDead property

    // Initialize the player variable
    public void SetPlayer(Fighter newPlayer)
    {
        player = newPlayer;
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 delta = Vector3.zero;

        // Check if the lookAt object is not null
        if (lookAt != null)
        {
            // To check if inside the bounds on X axis
            float deltaX = lookAt.position.x - transform.position.x;
            if (Mathf.Abs(deltaX) > boundX)
            {
                delta.x = deltaX > 0 ? deltaX - boundX : deltaX + boundX;
            }

            // To check if inside the bounds on Y axis
            float deltaY = lookAt.position.y - transform.position.y;
            if (Mathf.Abs(deltaY) > boundY)
            {
                delta.y = deltaY > 0 ? deltaY - boundY : deltaY + boundY;
            }

            // Apply position adjustment
            transform.position += delta;

            // Rotate the camera to look at the target
            transform.LookAt(lookAt);
        }
    }

    public void SwitchTodeathCameraTarget(Transform deathCameraTarget)
    {
        if (player != null && player.IsDead)
        {
            originalLookAt = deathCameraTarget;
            lookAt = originalLookAt;
        }
    }

    public void ResetToOriginalLookAt()
    {
        // Reset the lookAt to the originalLookAt
        lookAt = originalLookAt;
    }
}
```

this is my fighter script (controlling HP and deaths):

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class Fighter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int hitpoint = 10;
    public int maxHitpoint = 10;
    public float pushRecoverySpeed = 0.2f;

    protected float immuneTime = 1.0f;
    protected float lastImmune;

    protected Vector3 pushDirection;

    public bool IsDead { get; private set; }

    private CameraMotor cameraMotor;

    void Start()
    {
        cameraMotor = FindObjectOfType<CameraMotor>();
    }

    protected virtual void ReceiveDamage(Damage dmg)
    {
        if (Time.time - lastImmune > immuneTime)
        {
            lastImmune = Time.time;
            hitpoint -= dmg.damageAmount;
            pushDirection = (transform.position - dmg.origin).normalized * dmg.pushForce;

            GameManager.instance.ShowText(dmg.damageAmount.ToString(), 35, Color.white, transform.position, Vector3.zero, 0.5f);

            if (hitpoint <= 0)
            {
                hitpoint = 0;
                Death();
            }
        }
    }

    public virtual void Death()
    {
        IsDead = true;

        if (cameraMotor != null)
        {
            GameObject deathCameraTargetObject = GameObject.Find("deathCameraTarget");

            if (deathCameraTargetObject != null)
            {
                Transform deathCameraTarget = deathCameraTargetObject.transform;
                cameraMotor.SwitchTodeathCameraTarget(deathCameraTarget);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError("deathCameraTarget GameObject not found in the scene.");
            }
        }

        StartCoroutine(DestroyAfterDelay(2.0f));
    }

    private IEnumerator DestroyAfterDelay(float delay)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);

        if (cameraMotor != null)
        {
            cameraMotor.ResetToOriginalLookAt();
        }

        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: does it run the code? what happens when you debug it  - what do you see?

Comment: it doesn't look like you ever set the player.  In Start of Fighter, add cameraMotor.SetPlayer(this);